# Why am I getting an error saying can't find the variable length?

Tags: java

I'm not sure why it's thinking that this is a variable.

```
public boolean check(String arg) {
    if (arg.length = 4) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Also, if I wanted to add another condition, for example the length of the string has to equal 4 and there has to be a integer as the first character, how would I link the two 'if' statements?

Answer (score 4):

`length()` is a method of `String`, not a variable. Also you'll need to use `==` to compare the result of `arg.length()` and `4`, `=` is used to assign:

```
public boolean check(String arg) {
    if (arg.length() == 4){
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the '==' operator to compare the length of the string to your constant.

```
return arg.length() == 4;
```

You combine logical expressions using:

```
||  for 'or'
&& for 'and'
```

You can use `Character.isDigit` to see if the first character is a digit. Giving you the final expression:

```
return arg.length() == 4 && Character.isDigit(arg.charAt(0));
```

Comment: Do you not need an if statement? Or would returning it automatically give true if correct?

Comment: @J.Extra since the result of the evaluation is of `boolean` type, you can return it directly without needing an if statement.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to the first part of your question is:

1. A string's length is not a field.  Use `arg.length()` to get a string's length.  The error message is saying "can't find variable length", because `arg.length` is attempting to access a field of `String` that does not exist in the String API.
2. You compare things using either `==` or the `equals` method ... and not with `=`.  The `=` operator is the **assignment** operator.

---

> If I wanted to add another condition, for example the length of the string has to equal 4 and there has to be a integer as the first character, how would I link the two 'if' statements?

There are two answers:

```
if (arg.length() == 4 && Character.isDigit(arg.charAt(0)) {
    return true;
}
// do more stuff
```

or

```
if (arg.length() == 4) {
    if (Character.isDigit(arg.charAt(0)) {
        return true;
    }
}
// do more stuff
```

In this example, the first form is more readable (for an experienced Java programmer), and therefore recommended.  In more complicated examples, use of nested `if` statements *may be* better.

---

There are a couple of other points to make:

```
public boolean check(String arg) {
    if (arg.length() == 4) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

is a compilation error.  The Java compiler will tell you (in effect) that one of the return paths for the `check` method does not return a value.  What is going to happen if the length is not `4`?  The code doesn't say whether to return `true` or `false`.

If we rewrite is as follows:

```
public boolean check(String arg) {
    if (arg.length() == 4) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

the code will now compile.  But any experienced Java programmer will point out that you have used 5 lines of code to do something that can be done in just one line.

```
public boolean check(String arg) {
    return arg.length() == 4;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use logical operators to perform your task.

```
 return arg.length() == 4 && Character.isDigit(arg.charAt(0));
```

Also to clear things up, you can just return your if statement rather than testing if your condition is true and returning true.